# How to pkill process with a space in the name ("Web Content") in a python script

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess

Good Day, this should be fairly straight forward, but my googling and experimenting is not working.

I have a scraping script in python that uses Selenium/geckodriver/Firefox that runs on an Ubuntu 18 server. Sometimes it does not close properly and Selenium will crash midscript but it leaves many `Web Content` processes open.  If not closed they use up all the memory and then selenium can no longer open and the script fails.

If I run from the command line: `pkill 'Web Content'` it will kill those processes and free up the memory.

In my python script I use the `subprocess` module to try and automate this upon Selenium crashing.  I've tried a number of options including:

- `subprocess.call("pkill 'Web Content'".split())`
- `subprocess.call("pkill 'Web\ Content'".split())`
- `subprocess.call("pkill Web\ Content".split())`
- `subprocess.call("pkill -f Web\ Content".split())`

And all of these throw the same error: `pkill: only one pattern can be provided`

Yet, if I do something like `subprocess.call("pkill firefox".split())` the code is able to run without an error.

What must I do to resolve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: `subprocess.call(["pkill", "Web Content"])`

Comment: It appears to be working, I am just testing to see if it is actually killing the process. I probably don't understand subprocess fully as I thought you had to do one word per list item as it's input.

Comment: It is one argument per list item, not one word. That seems what caused the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually splitting the command line yourself simplifies the entire question significantly.

```py
subprocess.run(['pkill', 'Web Content'], check=True)
```

If you genuinely need Python to perform the splitting, `shlex.split()` implements the rules which you assumed Python's regular `split` function would obey. It doesn't; it simply splits on the string you supply, with no support for escaping etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

Use `subprocess.call("pkill 'Web Content'", shell=True)`  or

`subprocess.call(shlex.split("pkill 'Web Content'"))`

**Option 1**

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

> On POSIX with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a
> string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell.
> This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be
> when typed at the shell prompt.

`split()` splits Python string around spaces:

```
>>> "pkill 'Web Content'".split()
['pkill', "'Web", "Content'"]
```

So `subprocess.call("pkill 'Web Content'".split())` supplies two arguments to `pkill`: `"'Web"` and `"Content'"` while it expects only one. That's why error `pkill: only one pattern can be provided` pops.

Note the `subprocess.call` [signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) which is equivalent to `subprocess.Popen`:

`subprocess.Popen(args,..`

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> args should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string
> or path-like object. By default, the program to execute is the first
> item in args if args is a sequence.

Also note [security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) while using `shell=True`

**Option 2**

If you want to supply the args sequence use `shlex.split`:

```
>>> s = "pkill 'Web Content'"
>>> import shlex
>>> args = shlex.split(s)
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(args)
```

`shlex.split` would [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) the string `s` using shell-like syntax.

It's up to you which option to use, note relevant information in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/1264304):

> Understand shell=True vs shell=False With shell=True you pass a single
> string to your shell, and the shell takes it from there.
>
> With shell=False you pass a list of arguments to the OS, bypassing the
> shell.
>
> When you don't have a shell, you save a process and get rid of a
> fairly substantial amount of hidden complexity, which may or may not
> harbor bugs or even security problems.
>
> On the other hand, when you don't have a shell, you don't have
> redirection, wildcard expansion, job control, and a large number of
> other shell features.

Comment: Supplying `shell=True` just to get the shell to perform splitting of the command back into a list of strings seems like severe overkill. See also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in `subprocess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Comment: Thanks. I've offered 2 options. Second uses `shlex.split`.